# Why won't my labels stay changed

Tags: c#

when i run my code the labels stay the same but when i debug it i can see the text changes and then changes back when it is done runnning

```
public void getData(string a) 
{
    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=MASSI\FABERSERVER;Initial Catalog=Data.mdf;Integrated Security=True");
    conn.Open();
    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("Select UserID,UserName,Email FROM Login Where UserName= '" + a + "'", conn);
    SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();

    while (reader.Read())
    {
        label1.Text = reader["UserID"].ToString();
        label2.Text = reader["UserName"].ToString();
        label3.Text = reader["Email"].ToString();
    }

    conn.Close();
}
```

Comment: WebForms? WinForms? WPF?

Comment: You are probably after 1 row only. Your While loop should exit after that single row is found and also, you should add logic for when that row is not found using if (reader.HasRows). This link discusses a somewhat better way: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7836517/enforce-only-single-row-returned-from-datareader but I guess it is a bit advanced.

Comment: Your application is open to SQL injection. Use parameterized queries instead.

Comment: Are you reloading the form and then not calling getData() again?   The changes will not persist automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case, try this:

```
public void getData(string a) {
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=MASSI\FABERSERVER;Initial Catalog=Data.mdf;Integrated Security=True");
        conn.Open();
        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("Select UserID,UserName,Email FROM Login Where UserName= '" + a + "'", conn);
        SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();

        string id, name, email;

        while (reader.Read())
        {
            id = reader["UserID"].ToString();
            name = reader["UserName"].ToString();
            email = reader["Email"].ToString();

        }
        conn.Close();

        label1.Text = id;
        label2.Text = name;
        label3.Text = email;
    }
}
```

Hope, it helps.